# How to Add a panel to a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

so im kinda new to programming and I'm having a weird problem. So I'm trying to add my 'Info' panel with labels in them to my 'JFrame' but when I run the program the panel doesn't show up. Also how would I make it to where the panel would appear in the top Left of the JFrame.

```
private Lilac player;
private int[] xPos;
private JLabel lblShowLives, lblShowScore, lblTimer;
private int lives, score, seconds, minutes;
private ImageIcon[] imgBackground;
private Timer backgroundTimer, cutsceneTimer, Timer;
private AudioStream auStream;
private AudioPlayer auPlayer;
private InputStream in;
private DecimalFormat df, df2;


public FreedomPlanet() {

    df = new DecimalFormat("00");
    df2 = new DecimalFormat("0000");

    auPlayer = AudioPlayer.player;

    // creates the player
    player = new Lilac();

    // 
    lives = 3;
    score = 0;
    seconds = 0;
    minutes = 0;

    imgBackground = new ImageIcon[2];
    // gets the image for the background inside of a for loop   
    for (int i = 0; i < imgBackground.length; i++)
    {
        imgBackground[i] = new ImageIcon("Stage\\Forest.gif");
    } 
    xPos = new int[] {0, imgBackground[0].getIconWidth()};

    // sets the amount of time for each timer
    backgroundTimer = new Timer(50, this);
    Timer = new Timer(1000, this);

    // creates a label that displays "TIME"
    JLabel lblTime = new JLabel("TIME");
    lblTime.setFont(new Font("Britannic Bold", Font.BOLD, 18));

    // label that displays the time
    lblTimer = new JLabel();
    lblTimer.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 30));
    lblTimer.setFont(new Font("Britannic Bold", Font.BOLD, 18));
    lblTimer.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblTimer.setText(df.format(minutes) + ":" + df.format(seconds));

    // creates a label that says "SCORE"
    JLabel lblScore = new JLabel("SCORE");
    lblTime.setFont(new Font("Britannic Bold", Font.BOLD, 18));

    // label that displays the users score
    lblShowScore = new JLabel();
    lblShowScore.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 30));
    lblShowScore.setFont(new Font("Britannic Bold", Font.BOLD, 18));
    lblShowScore.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblShowScore.setText(df.format(score));

    // creates a panel called Info and and adds components to them
    JPanel Info = new JPanel();
    Info.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 10, 10));
    Info.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(270, 180));
    Info.add(lblTime);
    Info.add(lblTimer);
    Info.add(lblScore);
    Info.add(lblShowScore);


    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    setLayout(null);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(Info);
    frame.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setContentPane(this);
    frame.setTitle("Freedom Planet");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.addWindowListener(this);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setSize(imgBackground[0].getIconWidth(), imgBackground[0].getIconHeight());
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    // starts the background timer
    backgroundTimer.start();
    //Timer.start();

    // sets the location of the player
    player.setLocation(170, 395);

    Timer.start();

}
```

Comment: `setLayout(null);` - First problem. Without a layout manager you components have no default size or location. You shouldn't use components like this to make games, you should be using custom painting to paint the game state (and the components for various static elements if needed)

Comment: Maybe have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for more details about how painting works